# Display image using Glide and Retrofit from local computer memory

Tags: android, retrofit, android-glide

I have an android application which stores image in XAMMP (i.e C:\xammp\htdocs\php\imagefolder) at the time of registration. i am using XAMMP as local server, Retrofit for network activities and glide for image processing. Image is uploading successfully and image path is being stored in DATABASE. Now when i retrieve the information from database, i want to display that image in imageView using glide but i don't understand how i do that. In JSON response i am getting the path of the image and i am also fetching the json object from json array perfectly. But the problem is image is not loading with the help of glide

This is my image path retrieved from database `imagefolder/1234abc.jg`

This is actual path if image in my computer `C:\xammp\htdocs\php\imagefolder\1234.jpg`

and this is how i tried to load the image

```
Glide.with(this).load(ROOT_URL+OwnerPhoto).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(header_imageview);



Glide.with(this).load(OwnerPhoto).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(header_imageview);
```

and both methods failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have your device or emulator in same network or wifi, then 
on your computer find your ip address. must be like this:
`192.168.x.x or etc`

and use this ip address as `ROOT_URL`

instead of :

```
ROOT_URL = "C:\xammp\htdocs\php\imagefolder\1234.jpg"
```

use:

```
ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.x.x/php/imagefolder/1234.jpg"
```

hope it help you.